# Display Format for datetime is not working in edit mode in MVC Core and bootstrap 4

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a `DateTime` property in my model decorated as

```
  [Display(Name = "Valid From")]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
  public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
```

When I am using it in html's table's td its format is rendering correctly. This is how I am using it when it renders correctly - `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ValidFrom)`

Its not working in edit/create mode. This is how it created in view by default by scaffolding

`<input asp-for="ValidFrom" class="form-control"  />`

When edit/create form loads it has

Tried by specifying explicit date format but not working

```
<input asp-for="ValidFrom" class="form-control"  data-date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy"   />
```

[image]

This is how it renders on the form. Can you please guide what actually missing. Also, how can I set date format of date picker control to dd-MMM-yyyy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <input asp-for="ValidFrom" class="form-control"  />
> ```

By using above code, it will generate a `<input type= "date" />` element, by default the date format is "mm/dd/yyyy". To change the date format, you could try to change the date type to text type, like this:

```
<input asp-for="ValidFrom" class="form-control" data-date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy" type="text" placeholder="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
```

Then, the output as below:

[image]

Then, when you change the date, you could use Bootstrap-datepicker or JQuery UI datepicker to select date and change the date format.

[Note] If you are using both Bootstrap and JQuery UI, you might meet the JQuery conflict error, here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027220/cant-get-bootstrap-datepicker-to-show-in-a-asp-net-core-3-1-web-app/60032480#60032480), you could check it.

Comment: Thanks for the exact solution. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not specifying the type on your input

Your date format looks incorrect

I have found issues using asp-for with DateTime model properties (although these may work with string values)

Here is what I have been using in MVC Core 3. Hopefully this will be of help

```
<input type="date" value="@Model.DateTo.ToHtmlInputDate()" asp-for="DateTo" min="@Model.EarliestDate.ToHtmlInputDate()" max="@Model.LatestDate.ToHtmlInputDate()" onchange="$('form').submit();" class="form-control">
```

Here is my static helper to extend DateTime

```
public static string ToHtmlInputDate(this DateTime d)
{
    return d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Comment: Actually we need this date format (dd-MMM-yyyy i.e XX-MonthShortName-XXXX) only

Comment: I've looked back over a couple of MVC 5 and 6 projects and although I am a big advocate of the date format you propose, it looks like all of the formats I have used over the last few years tie in with what the control requires in order to work. It might be you can have a text box with the format you want and pop up a calendar to change that text. I think the vanilla approach to dates is the format I have specified

Answer (score 0):

By setting `false` to the `DisplayFormat` attribute, I could have it to work in .net 6 and .net 5 MVC

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Date saisine")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public DateTime? Birth {get; set;}
```